# My jQuery nested function can't return a value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery plugin with a nested function (stored on the data object so that I can call it later on). My problem is that when I call this function it seems that it can't return a simple value, it either returns undefined or the html object the plugin is attached to...

```
    var findTheObject = function(self,needle) {

        var haystack = self.data('galleryData');
        console.log('haystack is:');
        console.log(haystack);

        console.log('needle is:');
        console.log(needle);

        for (i = 0; i < haystack.length; ++i) {
            console.log('looking for needle...');
            if (haystack[i]['fileId'] == needle) {
                console.log('found needle:');
                console.log(haystack[i]);
                return haystack[i];
            }
        }

        return 'found no match';
    };
    this.data('findTheObject',findTheObject); //make callable later on through the data array.
```

I call it like this:

```
        if (self.data("activeFolder") != null) {
            var needle = self.data("activeFolder");
            var haystack = self.data('galleryData');

            current = null;
            //find the object corresponding to data("activeFolder")

            current = self.data(findTheObject(self,needle));

            console.log('returned object is:');
            console.log(current);
```

Comment: Use it like `self.data('findTheObject')(self,needle)`

Comment: curious - what happened with my way of calling it - the function worked just fine, I could read my console.log debug statements, the only thing that didn't work the return value...

Comment: In statement `self.data(findTheObject(self,needle))`, first you are calling global function `findTheObject` then whatever it returns suppose a string `abc` then it is looking for `self.data('abc')`

Comment: If you post your solution as an answer I can check it off..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

quote (Satpal):

Use it like self.data('findTheObject')(self,needle)

In statement self.data(findTheObject(self,needle)), first you are calling global function findTheObject then whatever it returns suppose a string abc then it is looking for self.data('abc')

close quote.

I like to check my questions off when they are answered. Cred for this answer goes to [Satpal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1668533/satpal) but since he has chosen not to post it as an answer I will summarize his answer (Satpal if you post an answer I will check that instead and remove my own to give you the cred).

Comment: [Related](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) - bottom line is, don't feel bad about answering questions like this :)